# Регулярные выражения C# - литералы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

появился такой вопрос. Это лабораторная работа, в ней есть два тестовых файла в котором 1 файл заменяет данные во втором.
Нужно сделать похожую программу, только с таким условием:
В тексте программы выделить литералы языка программирования. Разбить литералы на группы: целочисленные, вещественные, символьные и строковые. Указать для каждой группы литералов список литералов и их количество в группе.
Не пойму как сделать, был бы очень благодарен если бы кто-то написал правильный код, для наглядного примера. Спасибо!
Вот пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservedWords
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] reservedWordsArray = File.ReadAllLines("reservedWords.txt");
            Dictionary<string, int> reservedWords = Enumerable.Range(0, reservedWordsArray.Length).ToDictionary(x => reservedWordsArray[x]);

            string program = File.ReadAllText("Program.cs");

            foreach(string word in reservedWords.Keys)
            {
                program = Regex.Replace(program, $"(^|\\W)({word})($|\\W)", $"$1{word.ToUpper()}_{reservedWords[word]}$3");
            }

            File.WriteAllText("Program.txt", program.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут код на заказ не пишут, сайтом ошиблись.
Но помочь сделать я могу, подсказать правильное решение.

Итак, мы имеем 4 вида литералов:

- целочисленные (`10`, `0xFF`, `-1829`, `0b100001`)
- вещественные (`0.5`, `1.8e3`, `-1.8e-2f`)
- символьные (`'Q'`, `'\x0032'`, `(char)32`, `'\u0032'`)
- строковые (`"Q"`, `"10"`, `"0.5"`, `"test"`, `"Компания \"Рог\""`, `"Файл 'kek.txt'"`)

*Замечание: на самом деле со строковыми литералами всё не так просто. Например, внутри строкового литерала с регулярным выражением может находиться вообще всё что угодно. Я уже молчу про `$"text {1 + 8} text"`, что по сути литералом и не является.*

Для поиска совпадений и их вхождения в тексте используется регулярные выражения, класс `Regex`. Регулярки без труда можно найти в интернете, если самому не получается написать.
Так как эта лаба, то, возможно, вам и не придётся так сильно заморачиваться с обработкой всех случаев, что я привёл.

Для простоты:

- целочисленные - просто числа
- вещественные - числа с точной
- символьные - в одинарных кавычках
- строковые - в двойных кавычках

Находим каждый тип и сохраняем в массив, чтобы потом их вывести и подсчитать количество. Лучше собирать сразу объекты результата поиска регуляркой - [`Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netcore-3.1).

Затем открываем файл и заменяем найденные литералы из файла по результатам матчей. Сохраняем файл. Вот и всё, осталось вывести массивы с ранее найденными совпадениями и их количество.